# marking a grid with default values c++

Tags: c++, grid

I am trying to iterate through a grid in c++ and mark every coordinate as false.  What I thought I had done was create a 25x25 grid but VC++ is giving me two errors:

```
(37)"error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"

(44)"error C2448: 'markAllIncluded' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition"
```

I am using the stanford c++ lib for some of my header files.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "console.h"
#include "maze.h"
#include "gwindow.h"
#include "grid.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include <array>

using namespace std;
//prototypes

const int numCols = 25;
const int numRows = 25;

Vector<int> rand_coords();
Grid<bool> markAllIncluded(numCols, numRows);

int main() {

    Vector <int> coords = rand_coords(); //get random coords
    cout << "(" << coords[0] << ", " << coords[1] << ")" << endl;


    Grid<bool> included = markAllIncluded();
    string x = included.toString();
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}

Grid<bool> markAllIncluded() {

    Grid<bool> m(numRows, numCols); 

    for (int i=0; i <= numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= numCols; j++) {
            m.set(i, j, false);
        }
    }

    return m;

}


Vector<int> rand_coords () {

    Vector<int> coords(2);

    coords[0] = randomInteger(0, numCols);
    coords[1] = randomInteger(0, numRows);

    //cout << "(" << coords[0] << ", " << coords[1] << ")" << endl;

    return coords;

}
```

Is my syntax wrong? I get my error in main() when I set included to markAllIncluded()l

Comment: Did you just edit your code to fix the bug? Please **don't do that**, because now the answers lack context (they refer to a problem that doesn't exist). If you still have issues, open a new question or resolve it in chat.

Comment: Apologies, I will edit it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your syntax is wrong. The function declaration

```
Grid<bool> markAllIncluded(numCols, numRows);
```

is incorrect. You should use

```
Grid<bool> markAllIncluded();
```

(since `numRows` and `numCols` are global `const`s), or

```
Grid<bool> markAllIncluded(int numCols, int numRows);
```

Same goes for the definition later.

Comment: Thanks for the help nneonneo.  This certainly cleared up the inability to evaluate to a function taking x arguments.  I am now getting "cannot convert from 'Vector<ValueType> (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Vector<ValueType>'" and same inability for the Grid.

Comment: Leave the function calls intact -- `Vector <int> coords = rand_coords ();` was right.

Comment: ah yikes didn't catch that.

Comment: I got excited and started changing everything!

Comment: Well, you successfully confused everyone else about functions vs. objects. Try not to confuse yourself :) You have functions, so you call the functions.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo.  It is still plaguing me, though: I get a runtime error but it compiles just fine.  When I debug it refers me to my grid.h "if (!inBounds(row, col)) error("set: Grid indices out of bounds");" but I'm iterating through my grid so I'm not sure how this could be

Comment: You used `<=` instead of `<`, so you accessed `numRows` index. That's out of bounds because indices go from 0 to `numRows-1`.